# HttpClient exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host parameter is null while sending a request using using GetMethod()

Tags: java, web-services, apache-commons-httpclient

First of all my question is not duplicate to others. I am querying my question from last 2 days but didn't found any solution.The solutions I found were for the `PostMethod` but I have issue is `GetMethod`.
Due to some confidential data issue I cannot share the exact endpointUrl but I am giving a dummy endpointUrl.
below code was working fine and returning a csv file until the `endPointUrl` was  `https://abcxyz.com/incident.do?CSV` (abcxyz is the only dummy part here), :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
Credentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password);
client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);

GetMethod method=new GetMethod(endPointUrl);
int status = client.executeMethod(method);
```

Then I came in need to change endPointUrl which became  `https://abcxyz.com/incident.do?CSV&sys_param_query=active=true^sys_updated_onBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate(%272016-11-20%27,%2700:10:00%27)@javascript:gs.dateGenerate(%272016-11-24%27,%2712:59:59%27)` and then the above code started giving `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri` exception. Then I googled this and found that for larger urls or complex url we need to encode(UTF-8) them correctly using `URLEncoder.encode(endPointUrl, UTF-8)`. And the code became :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
Credentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password);
client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);

GetMethod method=new GetMethod(URLEncoder.encode(endPointUrl, UTF-8));
int status = client.executeMethod(method);
```

Now this code started complaining about `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host parameter is null`
Again I tried to solve this and came up with some solution as below:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
Credentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password);
client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);

HostConfiguration hf=new HostConfiguration();
hf.setHost("ven01623.service-now.com", 443); 
GetMethod method=new GetMethod(URLEncoder.encode(endPointUrl, UTF-8));
method.setHostConfiguration(hf);
int status = client.executeMethod(method);
```

But now, it is complaining `org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException: invalid port number` and I have no clue what to do now because it is a https connection to which has port number 443.

I am having one more question here, `https://abcxyz.com/incident.do?CSV` is running fine under `GetMethod method=new GetMethod(endPointUrl);` then why is it complaining **host parameter is null** under `GetMethod method=new GetMethod(URLEncoder.encode(endPointUrl, UTF-8));` ?
In Very much need of help.
Thanks

Comment: Despite its name, URLEncoder is for encoding parameter names and values, not entire URLS. You need to use the URI class to correctly encode URLs.

Comment: @EJP I don't think uri encoding is the issue, because I printed the uri `new GetMethod(URLEncoder.encode(endPointUrl, UTF-8)).getURI();` and it printed `https%3A%2F%2Fabcxyz.com%2F%2Fincident.do%3FCSV` which is the correct encoding i guess according to javaDoc